# What is the best way to draw highlight an excel report cell for viewing and b/w printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, highlighting

First off: I did search, and didn't find anything really duplicating what I want to ask, but it may be subjective, so I'll make it a community wiki.

I want to ask what the best way to highlight or draw attention to a cell in excel, that works well in both computer viewing, color printing, and black and white printing. The trick is, I need two separate levels - a "warning" (which may correspond to yellow) and an "alert" (which may correspond to red). A light yellow cell fill seems to work well for all three of my situations, but I can't find another way to do this, distinguishable from "normal cells" but also from the light yellow fill in all three - computer viewing, color printing, black and white printing.

A red cell fill makes the cell unreadable in black and white printing.

I've thought about using a cell border, but the cells are already in rows that have borders, so it would have to be a "thick border" and even then it doesn't quite stand out as much.

What do you think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the background to black and the text to white